# Qt QPlainTextEdit background

Tags: c++, qt

I want to change the background color of a `QPlainTextEdit`, how do I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Modify the palette of your plain text edit.  Sample program:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPlainTextEdit>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QPlainTextEdit edit;
  QPalette p = edit.palette();

  p.setColor(QPalette::Active, QPalette::Base, Qt::red);
  p.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::Base, Qt::red);

  edit.setPalette(p);

  edit.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Substitute whatever color you want, of course.

Comment: Note that with this method, applying style sheets to a parent or the control itself will disable this palette. Had some fun troubleshooting this just now :)

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I haven't worked with style sheets yet, so thanks for the advance notice.

Answer (score 4):

If QPlainTextEdit supports style sheets, you could do it like this:

```
myPlainTextEdit->setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow");
```

or

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("QPlainTextEdit {background-color: yellow}");
```

Comment: Note that this also affects the scrollbar color which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly confusingly they call it role rather than colour/color.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setBackgroundRole

hint - if you can't find a function for a particular control, click on show inherited members - most general settings are in qWidget which is the basis for eveything drawn on screen.

Comment: Haven't used it but see this thread http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-07/thread00174-0.html

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to call `QPlainTextEdit::setBackgroundVisible(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify the background, you need to modify the [palette](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpalette.html) of your QPlainTextEdit and to set background visible:

```
myPlainTextEdit->setPalette(QPalette(/*Select the constructor you need*/));
myPlainTextEdit->setBackgroundVisible(true);
```