# How to get widget background QColor

Tags: qt, qwidget

I am trying to find out the background color of a `QWidget` or `QGLWidget` so that I can use it with `qglClearColor()` to make the OpenGL part appear natively within the widget (without for example a black background).

I figured I could fetch `backgroundRole()` of my widget but I am having problems converting it to a `QColor`. There is `QPalette::color(QColorRole)` but it isn't static and I have no idea how I would have to create an instance of `QPalette` to do the transformation.

Comment: Did you try calling `qApp->palette()` to obtain application-wide palette and then call `QPalette::brush()` or `QPalette::color()`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `QWidget::palette().color(QWidget::backgroundRole())`to receive the color of the background color role for that widget. Obviously, this should also work with any class that inherits QWidget.

Comment: Your call to `qglClearColor` is NOT in your QGLWidget subclass's constructor right? It should be in intializeGL, paintGL, or any otherone of the functions that can only be called AFTER your OpenGL context is established.

Comment: Yes, it is in initializeGL. I forgot to add `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` to `paintG()`.

Comment: Hm... I am trying this with a control that inherits `QPlainTextEdit` and it doesn't seem to work (`auto cr = pte->backgroundRole();
    QPalette p = pte->palette();
    QColor col = p.color(cr);`). I don't know if I am missing sth. I have found some code for setting its background that is totally different but working (at least on Windows that I tested it): http://stackoverflow.com/a/1532179/964053. I have tried getting the color like so: `ui->plainTextEdit->palette().base().color()`, but it's my impression that this doesn't work all of the times. So, confusing the whole Qt palette class...